# Identify pairs or groups of rows that have the same values across multiple columns

Tags: r, dplyr

Say I have a data.frame:

```
file = read.table(text = "sex age num          
M 32 5
F 31 2
M 91 2
M 30 1
M 23 1
F 19 1
F 31 2
F 21 2
M 32 5
F 65 3
M 24 5", header = T, sep = "")
```

I want to get a sorted data frame of all rows that have the exact same values of `sex`, `age`, and `num` with any other row in the data frame.

The result should look like this (note that the data frame is sorted by the pairs or groups that are duplicated with each other):

```
result = read.table(text = "sex age num          
M 32 5
M 32 5
F 31 2
F 31 2", header = T, sep = "")
```

I have tried various combinations of `distinct` in dplyr and `duplicated`, but they don't quite get at this use case.

Answer (score 7):

We need `duplicated` twice i.e. one `duplicated` in the normal direction from up to bottom and second from bottom to top (`fromLast = TRUE`) and then use `|` so that it can be TRUE in either direction for subsetting

```
out <- file[duplicated(file)|duplicated(file, fromLast = TRUE),]
out$sex <- factor(out$sex, levels = c("M", "F"))
out1 <- out[do.call(order, out),]
row.names(out1) <- NULL
```

-output

```
> out1
  sex age num
1   M  32   5
2   M  32   5
3   F  31   2
4   F  31   2
```

---

The above can be written in `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
file %>%
   arrange(sex == "F", across(everything())) %>% 
   filter(duplicated(.)|duplicated(., fromLast = TRUE))
  sex age num
1   M  32   5
2   M  32   5
3   F  31   2
4   F  31   2
```

Comment: Thanks! This works, but it doesn't sort the duplicates by the pairs/groups that are identical. Any ideas on that front?

Comment: @Parseltongue updated.  The order for `sex` seems to be custom i.e. 'F' will be above 'M' alphabetically (unless we change it with `factor`)

Answer (score 7):

An alternative approach:

Here all groups with more then 1 nrow will be kept:

```
library(dplyr)

file %>% 
  group_by(sex, age, num) %>% 
  filter(n() > 1) %>%
  arrange(.by_group = T)
  ungroup()
```

```
 sex     age   num
  <chr> <int> <int>
1 F        31     2
2 F        31     2
3 M        32     5
4 M        32     5
```

Comment: Could you also add `arrange(.by_group = T)`?

Answer (score 4):

```r
file = read.table(text = "sex age num          
M 32 5
F 31 2
M 91 2
M 30 1
M 23 1
F 19 1
F 31 2
F 21 2
M 32 5
F 65 3
M 24 5", header = T, sep = "")

library(vctrs)
library(dplyr, warn = F)
#> Warning: package 'dplyr' was built under R version 4.1.2

file %>% 
  filter(vec_duplicate_detect(.)) %>% 
  arrange(across(everything()))
#>   sex age num
#> 1   F  31   2
#> 2   F  31   2
#> 3   M  32   5
#> 4   M  32   5
```

<sup>Created on 2022-08-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1.9000)</sup>

Comment: Nice option with `vec_duplicate_detect`

Answer (score 3):

Here is an approach, using `.SD[.N>1]` by group in `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
result = setDT(file)[, i:=.I][, .SD[.N>1],.(sex,age,num)][, i:=NULL]
```

Output:

```
   sex age num
1:   M  32   5
2:   M  32   5
3:   F  31   2
4:   F  31   2
```

Answer (score 2):

A base R option using `subset` + `ave`

```
> subset(file, ave(seq_along(num), sex, age, num, FUN = length) > 1)
  sex age num
1   M  32   5
2   F  31   2
7   F  31   2
9   M  32   5
```

or `rbind` + `split`

```
> do.call(rbind, Filter(function(x) nrow(x) > 1, split(file, ~ sex + age + num)))
         sex age num
F.31.2.2   F  31   2
F.31.2.7   F  31   2
M.32.5.1   M  32   5
M.32.5.9   M  32   5
```